# Problems with HD after reboot

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

My computer suddenly ran out of battery, and when i started it again, it doesnt recognize my external hd, and also is showing "efi" and "Filesystem root" options in the file explorer, and it does not show my second partition of the hd, that was only with pdf's and some codes.

Detail: Using Debian

[Other locations option in file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idkDQ.png)

[The options that appear in the file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avcPq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fsck can likely help fix. Easiest way to fix is to use a Live USB and boot into a Ubuntu Linux Live environment, open the 'Disks' utility and under the options, click the partition in quesiton, and try 'Repair the filesystem' under the 2 gears icon. If this is really sensitive data I think you may be able to mount it and copy off the files before you run the repair, though not always the case depending on how damaged Ubuntu thinks the partition is.

More info on fsck: https://www.tecmint.com/fsck-repair-file-system-errors-in-linux/